# Delphi migration fastreport issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have my Delphi application up and running in XE2.
I am using fastreport provided with IDE.

When i tried to migrate from Delphi XE2 to delphi 10.1, I get issues for fastreport.

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] fs_isysrtti.pas(615): F2051 Unit fs_iinterpreter was compiled with a different version of fs_isysrtti.TfsSysFunctions
```

I have added lib path in tools->options.
What can be issue over here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means what it says: there is a mismatch between the current version of fs_isysrtti and the one which was current when fs_iinterpreter was compiled. This is probably because the compiler is finding an out of date copy of fs_iinterpreter.dcu before the one it ought to find. Try searching your machine for versions of this .dcu file and renaming/hiding all except the newest (or the one in the same output folder as the compiler is trying to compile fs_isysrtti to, which is hopefully the same thing).

If your system is anything like mine (I have XE4 to D10 Seattle installed) you will find a number of versions of these dcus (fs_iinterpreter.dcu, that is).

Assuming this procedure removes the compiler's complaint, one-by-one reinstate the dcus you renamed or hid until the problem re-occurs and then you know which copy is causing the problem.  Then work out how the D10.1 compiler is managing to find it and prevent it.  Possibly, the compiler search path is causing it to look in the wrong place before the correct one.

Unfortunately, even if you manage to find the .dcu that's causing the problem, you may then find that the compiler raises a similar complaint about another Fast Report .dcu.  If is does, then your easiest option may simply be to hide/rename all the FR files and reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you for info.
The problem here is fastreport works in test application. It gives issue only for this particular application. May be something wrong in path.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall FR, install it again and remove pas files from LibD24 folder
or
install all updates for Delphi 10.1 Berlin and use latest FR 5.5.11

Comment: It works fine for all other application..even migrated ones.. It creates issue for only one application.

Comment: This error message will appear when FR's packages compiled with another Delphi 10.1 build. If some pas files present in the LibD23 folder - they will be recompiled and you will get this error. So you should remove pas files after FR's reinstallation or use latest FR with latest Delphi. There are no other solution

Answer (score 0):

I 've just got the same issue when I tried to convert old quickreport files to Fastreport 6.2.1 (Delphi 10.3.3  64 bit Target)
I found an easy solution here:
https://wiert.me/2016/06/30/built-in-delphi-xe6-xe7-and-xe8-fast-reports-have-issue-f2051-unit-fs_iinterpreter-was-compiled-with-a-different-version-of-fs_isysrtti-tfssysfunctions/

if the link wont work:
you have to move the *.pas files from the path
"c:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD26x64"
(it was my path, check yours. /where the fs_isysrtti.pas/)

and it works.